# Generating optimized autoloader automatically

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm working on a simple project using PHP and I'm using PSR-4 autoloading. I just wonder if there's a way to run `composer dump-autoload -o` on `composer install`, so that new users won't need to type `composer dump-autoload -o` to avoid autoloading error

```
{
    "name": "project/vendor",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "my name",
            "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
          "psr-4": {
              "src\\": "src/"
           }
     },
     "scripts": {
        "run-test": ["./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/calculatorTests.php"]
    }
}
```

Comment: dump-autoload -o is only to create an optimized autoload map for use in production. For development you don't need it, and just a composer install should suffice.

Comment: Actually after testing the code on another machine, i executed composer install but after i got an error which was a class is not found, and it worked just fine after executing composer dump-autoload

Comment: That should not happen. Could you update your post to include your full composer.json?

Comment: okay i updated the post and here's the link of the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oMT7.png

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: @anothermh i did thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use [`optimize-autoloader`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#optimize-autoloader) option in `composer.json` `config`:

```
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
```

However this may be quite annoying on development phase (when generating optimized autoloader is just waste of time and source of problems), so I would rather create some shortcut script for this and encourage users to use it instead of direct `composer dump-autoload` or `composer install`. See [this answer as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851185/php-composer-no-dev-mode-that-sticks/50776625#50776625). Then you can just use

```
composer install --no-dev -o
```

in your script.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for