# Prevent composer update in production environments

Tags: composer-php

We've just had an issue where I work, and someone launched the `composer update` command on a production environment, thus causing some problems.

Is there a way to prevent any `composer update` and allow only `composer install` on a specific environment ?

Comment: I suggest to revoke access to production server for that person - an unqualified person running random commands on the server can do far more damage than running `composer update`. Even `composer install` will install dev dependencies (it may create security issues) and you will not even notice it.

Comment: Alternatively you may create foolproof command for deployment, so nobody will be able to break anything by accident: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776625/5812455 . If you hide `composer` binary under some unexpected name, it may be safe enough.

Comment: @rob006, that's a nice one, thanks !